# R: Data layout of 2^4 Factorial Design

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array

I can at most read the data of a 3-way factorial design in R. But when the number of factors is more than 3, i can't read the data in R.

```
 #2^3 design 
 trt=c("000","100","010","110","001","101","011","111")
 m=array(trt,dim=c(2,2,2))
 m
```

How can i read the data of 2^4 Factorial Design in R ?

Comment: `(m2 <- array( seq( 0,16 ),dim=c( 2,2,2,2 ) ) )`

Answer (score 4):

Of course it depends how you will proceed with your data afterwards, but from my point of view a simple 2 dimensional `data.frame` should be very convenient to process afterwards plus you can generate the factorial designs rather easily:

```
expand.grid(a = 0:1, b = 0:1, c = 0:1, d = 0:1)
#    a b c d
# 1  0 0 0 0
# 2  1 0 0 0
# 3  0 1 0 0
# 4  1 1 0 0
# 5  0 0 1 0
# 6  1 0 1 0
# 7  0 1 1 0
# 8  1 1 1 0
# 9  0 0 0 1
# 10 1 0 0 1
# 11 0 1 0 1
# 12 1 1 0 1
# 13 0 0 1 1
# 14 1 0 1 1
# 15 0 1 1 1
# 16 1 1 1 1
```